# Kotlin Coroutine: Dispatchers inside Flow builder

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Extension functions that returns save Bitmap to device storage and returns result using sealed and class that represent its state.

```
sealed class RequestStatus<T> {
    data class Loading<T>(val data: T? = null) : RequestStatus<T>()
    data class Success<T>(val data: T) : RequestStatus<T>()
    data class Failed<T>(val error: Exception, val data: T? = null) : RequestStatus<T>() {
        val message = nullableErrorMsg(error.localizedMessage)
    }
}


fun View.createAndStoreScreenshot(
    appName: String,
    @ColorRes backgroundColor: Int
): Flow<RequestStatus<Uri>> = flow {

emit(RequestStatus.Loading())

... Some code

       try {
            
            FileOutputStream(imageFile).use { stream ->

                // Create bitmap screen capture
                val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(createBitmapFromView(backgroundColor))

                // This method may take several seconds to complete, so it should only be called from a worker thread.
                // Read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream)
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream)

                val uriForFile = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    "${context.applicationContext.packageName}.provider",
                    imageFile
                )

                emit(RequestStatus.Success(uriForFile))

            }
            
        }
        catch (e: Exception) {
            emit(RequestStatus.Failed(e))
        }

}
```

Usage

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {

      withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { 

          view.createAndStoreScreenshot(
               getString(R.string.app_name),
               R.color.colorWhite_PrimaryDark
              ).onEach { req ->
                          when (req) {
                            
                            is RequestStatus.Loading -> {

                            ...

                            }


                        }.collect()

      }

}
```

`FileOutputStream` is complaining as it can block UI thread, but you cannot switch context inside `flow` builder so we move on using `flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)` and remove the `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` from the caller. Now we the Android Studio is complaining `Not enough information to infer type variable T` when emitting **Loading** and **Failed** state but explicitly providing the data type also marked as redundant. What is the problem here?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `Uri?` not `Uri` for `Loading` and `Failed` state.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32321795)

Comment: @harre I think is this intended to be an answer.